# `'Column' object is not callable` when showing a single spark column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I'm a new spark user, and previously I'm from pandas background. Here's my Spark Dataframe

```
In[75]:  spDF
Out[75]: DataFrame[customer_id: string, name: string]
```

and when I `show` them

```
In[75]:  spDF.show()
Out[75]:

+-----------+-----------+
|customer_id|       name|
+-----------+-----------+
|      25620| MCDonnalds|
|      25620|  STARBUCKS|
|      25620|        nan|
|      25620|        nan|
|      25620| MCDonnalds|
|      25620|        nan|
|      25620| MCDonnalds|
|      25620|DUNKINDONUT|
|      25620|   LOTTERIA|
|      25620|        nan|
|      25620| MCDonnalds|
|      25620|DUNKINDONUT|
|      25620|DUNKINDONUT|
|      25620|        nan|
|      25620|        nan|
|      25620|        nan|
|      25620|        nan|
|      25620|   LOTTERIA|
|      25620|   LOTTERIA|
|      25620|  STARBUCKS|
+-----------+-----------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Then I try querying columns only

```
In[76]:  spDF['name']
Out[76]: Column<b'name'>
```

But when I show them, I get the following error.

```
In[79]: spDF['name'].show()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-f6676d5e5ca2> in <module>()
----> 1 spDF['name'].show()

TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

Anyone has an idea, what is this error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

So spDF.select('colname').show()

Comment: I stumbled across this while getting similar error. The answer provided by Chandan Ray is correct. To answer OP's question originally, why this happened? : I think it's because bracket notation returns a Column object and show() method is not defined for Column object. show() method is only defined for Dataframe object, which is why spDF.select().show() works because select() also return another Dataframe object.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

sc = pyspark.SparkContext('local[*]')
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
.
.
.
spDF.createOrReplaceTempView("space")
spark.sql("SELECT name FROM space").show()
```

The top two lines are optional to someone to try this snippet in local machine.